# И вновь о характеристиках Spring бинов

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring

Господа,

хотел бы для себя четко уяснить, существуют ли четкие связи между следующими парами терминов в связи с бинами Spring:

- singleton - prototype
- thread-safe - not-thread-safe
- stateful - stateless

Можно ли утверждать, что:

- prototype == thread-safe
- singleton != thread-safe
- prototype == stateful
- singleton == stateless

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Не верно. singleton - stateless, a prototype - stateful. "As a rule, use the prototype scope for all stateful beans and the singleton scope for stateless beans" (с)

Comment: Выше так и написано. Что "неверно"?

Comment: Да, действительно, все так. Не верно считал информацию, когда пробегал глазами по вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя. Синглтон может быть вполне себе потокобезопасным, а прототип делать какие-то непотокобезопасные вещи, пусть хоть статическое поле у своего класса обновлять. Если код пишется хорошо, то в нем не будет non-thread-safe вообще нигде.